# Iron-Router server side routing: TypeError and Infinite Reloading with iron-router blaze-integration

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, server-side, iron-router

I have created a simple Iron-Router test app that was meant to help me get a handle on server side routing (in addition to other things, but I am struggling with server side routing right now). I am currently using the blaze-integration branch in this project. My route looks like this (obviously, this is in CoffeeScript):

```
Router.map ->
  @route 'something',
    path: '/something'
    where: 'server'
    before: ->
      console.log @
    action: ->
      @response.writeHead 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
      @response.end 'hello from server!'
```

This route fails in my app, but in different ways depending on where I put the route. If I define this in it's own `router.coffee` within a `server` folder of my app, I get the following error when I trigger the route by trying to navigate to the path `/something`:

```
W20140306-16:49:25.347(-5)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'run'
W20140306-16:49:25.350(-5)? (STDERR)     at Utils.extend.run (packages/iron-router/lib/server/router.js:62)
W20140306-16:49:25.350(-5)? (STDERR)     at next (packages/iron-router/lib/router.js:272)
W20140306-16:49:25.352(-5)? (STDERR)     at IronRouter.dispatch (packages/iron-router/lib/router.js:278)
W20140306-16:49:25.352(-5)? (STDERR)     at packages/iron-router/lib/server/router.js:37
```

I'm not sure what this is, or how to resolve this issue. My attempt was to just put this exact same route where I defined all my other routes, in the `irtest.coffee` file in the `client` folder. If I do that, however, I don't get an error, but the page just continuously reloads.

So I guess my question is two-fold:

1. Why would my server route be malfunctioning in each of the above situations?
2. Where would be the most 'correct' place to define these server side routes?

Any other pointers are welcome, too! I'm pretty new to this stuff!

**PS** The full project can be seen and cloned [here](https://github.com/BloodChiefStromberg/iron-router-test).

**EDIT**
In accordance with Christian's tips in the comments, I split the routes into their own file called `router.coffee` located in the app's root. After doing this and trying to access `/something`, I get the same `TypeError` as I did before, when the routes were placed in the `client` and the `server` folder respectively.

Comment: routes should go into a file that is shared by the client and the server. If you use the `client/`, `server/`, layout for your app, then you can just put it into the root folder of your app. Do you get the server error on load of the app or only once you hit the route from a browser?

Comment: When I had it in the server folder, I got the error when trying trigger the route, not on the app load. I'll adjust my question to reflect this. Also, thanks for the tip about where to put it, I'll drop it in there and see if I have any luck.

Comment: I placed the file in the root folder, and get the same `TypeError` when triggering the root that I did when I placed the server route in the server folder. I added this to my question also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. Here is what I did:

1. meteor create test
2. cd test
3. created router.coffee with your code
4. mrt add iron-router
5. meteor add coffeescript
6. reloaded the page and got "hello from server" and an elaborate printout on the (server) console

It seems the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: When you're right, you're right. Still seems like a weird error though, and probably worth knowing why. I'm going to explore this a little more.

Comment: looking at your github repo I noticed that you seem to be using iron-router from github (blaze-integration branch). Maybe just try it with the version that `mrt` installs and see what happens.

Comment: Good call! Looks like that was the problem. Changing the branch to master in the smart.json for iron-router and then reinstalling it solved the problem, so it looks like it's a problem with that branch, which is by no means stable. I'll go ahead and post something on the project on github, in case this helps some how. You should probably edit your answer and point out what you told me here. Thanks man!